# When inviting a team member to an Outlook calendar event, is it possible for the event to be saved in one of their 'Other Calendars'?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

On our team, each member has their default Outlook calendar, for work or personal events, and then their appointments are on a separate calendar that can be shared with their managers.

If an appointment is updated to include another invitee, can that invite direct the appointment to their appointment calendar rather than their default calendar?

Answer (score 0):

A perfect answer to your question can be found in the Stack Overflow post
[How to post calendar event to participant's specific calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406069/how-to-post-calendar-event-to-participants-specific-calendar).

Short answer : No go. There are workarounds, but they are just as bad as the
original problem. You may be better off adding rules to everybody's
default calendar to do the job.

Here is the answer reproduced :

> Google Calendar, regardless of the API or the language you use, is
>   based on the iCalendar standard, which, from my readings of it, does
>   not have the concept of "Invite a participant and post event
>   invitation on this specific calendar of that participant."  If I'm
>   wrong, the quickest way to get your answer and prove me wrong is to
>   find evidence of such a feature in the iCalendar documentation.
>
> I thought I had a workaround, which is "Hey, if you have access to
>   person-B's calendar, why not just create the event on their calendar
>   and add person-A as an attendee?" I did this by sharing one of my
>   sub-calendars of one of my Google Calendar accounts with another. But
>   sure enough, you get the same problem in reverse. Now person-B has the
>   event in the right place, but person-A has it on their default
>   calendar.
>
> So depending on which is your "primary" account, you may want to go
>   that route, but I'm guessing you find that about as appealing as what
>   you're dealing with already.
>
> The only other workaround I found (which was not all that great), is
>   you can access Person-B's calendar and copy the invite to another
>   calendar (the one you want), and then delete it from the main
>   calendar. This will work (I tried it), but obviously it's not as
>   graceful as what you had in mind.